# Procedure works in mysql workbench but not with C++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a Procedure that executes in MySQL Workbench and gives no errors:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxwf_fir INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET maxwf_fir = (SELECT MAX(wf_fir) FROM establishment);
    WHILE maxwf_fir > 0 DO
        UPDATE individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING (establishment_id) SET 
        wf_fir = wf_fir-1,
        e.wf_est = e.wf_est-1,
        i.labor = 2,
        i.labor_periods = 0,
        i.establishment_id = 0
        WHERE (e.wf_hir <= e.wf_fir)
        AND (wf_fir > 0);

        UPDATE individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING (establishment_id) SET 
        e.counter1 = e.counter1+1
        WHERE (e.wf_hir <= e.wf_fir)
        AND (wf_fir > 0);

        UPDATE individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING (establishment_id) SET 
        e.counter1 = 0,
        e.counter2 = e.counter2+1
        WHERE (e.wf_hir <= e.wf_fir)
        AND (wf_fir > 0)
        AND (e.counter1 = e.wf_est);

        SET maxwf_fir = maxwf_fir-1;
    END WHILE;
END//

DELIMITER ;
CALL test;

DROP PROCEDURE test;
```

However when I use that some code with the C++ connector I get told there is a syntax error, but the code is exactly the same (I literally copied and pasted from the workbench into Geany):

```
std::stringstream query4;
//query4 << "drop procedure if exists loop;\n";
query4 << "DELIMITER //\n";
query4 << "CREATE PROCEDURE loop()\n";
query4 << "BEGIN\n";
query4 << "\tDECLARE maxwf_fir INT DEFAULT 0;\n";
query4 << "\tSET maxwf_fir = (SELECT MAX(wf_fir) FROM establishment);\n";
query4 << "\tWHILE maxwf_fir > 0 DO\n";
query4 << "\t\tUPDATE individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING (establishment_id) SET\n";
query4 << "\t\te.wf_fir = e.wf_fir-1,\n";
query4 << "\t\te.wf_est = e.wf_est-1,\n";
query4 << "\t\ti.labor = 2,\n";
query4 << "\t\ti.labor_periods = 0,\n";
query4 << "\t\ti.establishment_id = 0\n";
query4 << "\t\tWHERE (e.wf_hir <= e.wf_fir)\n";
query4 << "\t\tAND (e.wf_fir > 0)\n";
query4 << "\t\tAND e.temp < POW("<< Coeffs::gamma67 << ", e.counter2)*" << random << ";\n";

query4 << "\t\tUPDATE individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING (establishment_id) SET\n";
query4 << "\t\te.counter1 = e.counter1+1\n";
query4 << "\t\tWHERE (e.wf_hir <= e.wf_fir)\n";
query4 << "\t\tAND NOT (e.temp < POW("<< Coeffs::gamma67 << ", e.counter2)*" << random << ")\n";
query4 << "\t\tAND (wf_fir > 0);\n";

query4 << "\t\tUPDATE individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING (establishment_id) SET\n";
query4 << "\t\te.counter1 = 0\n";
query4 << "\t\te.counter2 = e.counter2+1\n";
query4 << "\t\tWHERE (e.wf_hir <= e.wf_fir)\n";
query4 << "\t\tAND NOT (e.temp < POW("<< Coeffs::gamma67 << ", e.counter2)*" << random << ")\n";
query4 << "\t\tAND e.counter1 = e.wf_est\n";
query4 << "\t\tAND (wf_fir > 0);\n";

query4 << "\t\tSET maxwf_fir = maxwf_fir-1;\n";
query4 << "\tEND WHILE;\n";
query4 << "END//\n";
query4 << "DELIMITER ;\n";
query4 << "CALL loop;\n";
query4 << "DROP PROCEDURE loop;\n";
stmt->execute(query4.str());
```

This gives me the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::SQLException'
  what():  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to     your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE loop()
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxwf_fir INT DEFAULT 0;
    SE' at line 1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong in the C++ code that is causing this error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Stored Procedure from an interface other than SQL engine, `delimiter` is optional. Example @ [*SQL FIddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adf8/1)

**Change 1**:

Remove the statement

```
query4 << "DELIMITER //\n";
```

**Change 2**:

`loop` is a [*Reserved Word*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). If you still want to use the same name for procedure, surround it with back ticks as

```
`loop()`
```

**Change 3**:

```
query4 << "END//\n";
```

**To**:

```
query4 << "END;\n"; // semi-colon is optional, if it is last statement in the sp
```

**Change 4**:

Remove the statement

```
query4 << "DELIMITER ;\n";
```

**Change 5**:

```
query4 << "CALL loop;\n";
query4 << "DROP PROCEDURE loop;\n";
```

**To**:

```
query4 << "CALL `loop`();\n";
query4 << "DROP PROCEDURE `loop`;\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, do what is mentioned in Ravinder's answer. "DELIMITER" statements are not needed when you call execute(), and API will be smart enough to understand that a semicolon inside a body of stored procedure is not the end of the command. In fact, c++ executeUpdate() complains about using "DELIMITER", but execute(), I guess, just silently fails.

Second, enable CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS option when creating a connection because you are trying to execute several statements at once. Or execute them one by one.

To enable multiple statements for C++ you may write something like:

```
sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
sql::Connection *con = driver->connect("tcp://host:3306", "user", "pass");
bool myTrue = true;
con->setClientOption("CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS", &myTrue);
```

or, use a different version of driver->connect(), something like this:

```
sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;
connection_properties["hostName"] = "host";
connection_properties["port"] = (3306);
connection_properties["userName"] = "user";
connection_properties["password"] = "pass";
connection_properties["CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS"] = (true);
sql::Connection *con = driver->connect(connection_properties));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is the name of the procedure "loop" is a reserved word, does it work in the workbench with "loop" instead of "test" ?

Comment: I think that would have been an issue in the future, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem, I am still getting the same error...